# How did Hiruzen Sarutobi summon Enma when he was a reanimation?

Tags: naruto

In the Fourth Great Ninja War, when Obito makes the Ten-Tails transform the into God Tree that devoured the chakra of all the shinobi it touched (or its branches), where you will see Sarutobi Hiruzen cutting/destroying the branches of the Ten-Tails' tree form, and he does that with the help of Enma's transformation - Adamantine Staff.

When Sandaime Hokage is summoned using the  "Impure World Reincarnation", you aren't supposed to have any blood in you to summon Enma.

[image]

So, now if you check the naruto wiki, to summon a contract animal, first of all we would need to have a blood contract with the summoning animal, Afterwards they only need to offer an additional donation of blood on the hand they signed the contract with, mould their chakra with hand seals and then plant the hand they signed the contract with at the location they wish to summon the creature.

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning_Technique

So, was it a flaw to show Sandaime Hokage with Adamantine Staff or is there any other technique this is used to summon a contract animal.
Or was this explained in Manga..

Answer (score 6):

I can recall two instances where Shinobi who are under the influence of [Impure World Reincarnation](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation) are shown to bleed while when performing a justu that requires blood or causes them to bleed.

While those reincarnated by Impure World Reincarnation do not bleed, it would appear reincarnated Shinobi do bleed as long as the injury is self applied (*speculative and don't have a reference, somebody correct me if I am wrong on this*).

The first instance is the Summoning Justu

> Reincarnated bodies do not bleed, except in those cases where blood is needed to perform the Summoning Technique

This is in reference to Naruto Chapter 548, when we see the reincarnated [2nd Mizukage](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Gengetsu_H%C5%8Dzuki) biting his thumb to perform the Summoning Justu against the Allied Shinobi Forces

[image]

The second instance is using the Mangekyou Sharingan

> Other side-effects may still manifest, as when Itachi Uchiha's eyes bleed from using his Mangekyō Sharingan, but he is not inhibited by it.

This is in reference to Naruto Chapter 550, when Naruto and Killer B are fighting against the reincarnated Nagato and Itachi. Itachi uses the Mangekyō Sharingan, causing his eyes to bleed

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I guess that makes sense...