# Why didn’t Tobirama bleed in Edo Tensei but Itachi did?

Tags: naruto

Itachi bled when he used Amaterasu, but I didn’t see Tobirama bleed.  I just want to know why he didn’t bleed, but Itachi did.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How did Hiruzen Sarutobi summon Enma when he was a reanimation?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43615/how-did-hiruzen-sarutobi-summon-enma-when-he-was-a-reanimation)

Answer (score -1):

The bleeding is apart of using the mayengekyo(unless it is eternal mayengekyo) so the effects of the jutsu can't be stopped